# What process does happen in 'Input Transform' in PointNet architecture?

Tags: conv-neural-network, classification, point-clouds

I am reading a papers to understand the method which convert the raw point cloud data into machine learning readable dataset. Here I would like to ask you one question that I have in the research paper  PointNet: Deep Learning on Point Sets for 3D Classification and Segmentation. I want to understand that in the PointNet architecture (shown in Picture below), in the first step, after taking the raw point cloud data into the algorithm, data goes into 'Input transform' part where some process happens in T-Net (Transformation network) and matrix multiplication. My question is 'What does happen in the 'Input Transform' and 'Feature transform' part? what is the input data and what is the output data? Kindly give an explanation about this as that was my main question.

You can find the research paper by the doi: 10.1109/CVPR.2017.16

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to work this out as well, consider this an incomplete answer. I think the Input transformer with a 3x3 matrix acts to spacially transform (via some affine transformation) the nx3 inputs (3 dimensional think x,y,z). Intuitively you may think of it this way: say you give it a rotated object (say an upside down chair), it would de-rotate the object to a canonical representation (an upright chair). Its a 3x3 matrix to preserve the dimensionality of the input. That way the input become invarient to changes of pose (perspective). After this the shared mlps (essentially a 1x1 conv) increase the number of features from nx3 to (nx64), the next T-net does the same as in the other example, it moves the higher dimensional feature space into a canonical form. As to exactly how the box works Im reading the code and will let you know.

Comment: Nice explanation! Any ideas why not using data augmentation instead of T-Net?